# What HTTP error response for XmlHttpRequest to fill in responseText field

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I send a request to a server using XmlHttpRequest. The request is processed on the server, and the server wishes to send an error 
response with explanatory text (in the body). I have tried many different response codes, but on the client (Chrome v33 or so) the XHR object's response is always empty.

Client:

```
   var formItem = document.forms.namedItem("regform"),
       formData = null;

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------
 * General validation - after all the above
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------- */


if (! formItem.checkValidity())
   {
   setup_register();
   return;
   }



formData = new FormData(formItem);

var req = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  url = "http://" + host + "...whatever.../registration";

console.log("Start Registration " + formData);

req.open("POST", url, true);

req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4)
        {
        if (this.status == 200)
            {
            console.log("Registration finished OK");


                     window.return_window.postMessage("Done", '*');
                    window.close();

                        }


        else
            {
            console.error("Registration failed" + req.status + " Text:" + req.responseText);

            return;
            }
        }
    };

req.send(formData);
```

Server:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/registration")
public ClientIdentification registration(
        @FormDataParam("username")  String username,
        @FormDataParam("firstname")  String firstname,
        @FormDataParam("password")  String password,
        @FormDataParam("lastname")  String lastname,
        @FormDataParam("verifypassword")  String verifypassword,
        @FormDataParam("businessname")  String businessname,
  ...
  ...
  throw new PisRsMessageException(e.getMessage(), HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
```

Where PisRsMessageException is a simple wrapper aound Jersy's WebApplicationException

I have sniffed this to make sure that the response is sent correctly. However the req.responseText is always empty.

I see that this is more or less the simple interpretation of W3C's standard - if the server returns an error, responseText should be empty. That is not helpful. I need to have a way of returning an error, but still having explanatory text.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20140130/#the-responsetext-attribute

A fallback would be to always return 200, but I don't want to do that if not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was forgetting the CORS headers in the case of an error, and this is the reason Chrome was wiping out the response text.